Laplace transform region of convergence of two subsequent poles
Suppose we have a function:
$$
f(t)= e^{-4t} + sin(t)e^{-2t},
$$
where the Laplace transform is given by the standard lookup table of individual transforms:
$$
F(s)=\frac{1}{s+4}+\frac{1}{(s+2)^2+1},
$$
where the definition that I use for the Laplace transform is given as:
$$
F(s)= \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt, \quad \text{where} \; s=\alpha+ j \omega.
$$
How can we ensure that the laplace transform is defined in the region $\alpha\in (-\infty,-2)$?
My reasoning is that since we have poles at $s=-2 \pm j$ the Laplace integral is undefined for $\alpha<-2$, because the $e^{-2t}$ term will be unbounded and therefore the value for $s$, when that condition holds, are not in the region of convergence  (ROC). However, with that reasoning you can never have two subsequent poles, because everything after the first pole is then not in the ROC and that is of course not true. I feel like it is more of a calculus issue than anything else, but I would appreciate if someone could shed some light on the confusion I have.

$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-4t}e^{-\alpha t} dt <\infty$ if $\alpha +4 >0$ and $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-2t}e^{-\alpha t} dt <\infty$ if $\alpha +2 >0$. Both of these hold for $\alpha >-2$.

Agreed, the Laplace integral is indeed defined for all $\alpha > -2$, but I am confused on what happens between $-4 < \alpha < -2$, because the pole at $s=-4$ from my reasoning above, should not be in the ROC due to the complex pole pair at $s=-2 \pm j$.
